# ImportError: cannot import name update_all_contenttypes

Tags: django, django-1.8

I upgraded recently to Django 1.8.  In previous versions of Django, the following import was fine:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_all_contenttypes
```

But `update_all_contenttypes` appears to have been silently removed in Django 1.8 (it was there in 1.7.7).  I'm not seeing anything in the [1.8 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/) about its removal...  Does anyone know what the modern replacement is for that function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's unclear why that function was removed in 1.8, but it appears that the modern replacement is to just re-invent that wheel:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes

def update_all_contenttypes(**kwargs):
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        update_contenttypes(app_config, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700638/update-all-contenttypes-seemingly-not-working-with-django-1-8

Comment: The function `update_contenttypes` has also been removed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems django team has removed the update_contenttypes function without a mention in the release notes because isn't a documented, public API. (as the said here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28092)

Now you can use instead the new function  create_contenttypes, as you can see here:
https://github.com/django/django/commit/6a2af01452966d10155b720f4f5e7b09c7e3e419

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the location of 'django.contrib.contenttypes' in your system (check your 'site-packages' folder of python)
- Open the app.py (You can use vi app.py in a terminal window)
- Replace 'update_contenttypes' with 'create_contenttypes'
- Save the file ('ESC', ‘:’ and ‘wq’ - in a vi editor)

Then try to run the server

Answer (score -1):

create a virtual environment and the error will vanished.

[find here how to create a virtual_env:](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#project-setup)