# django.setup() throws "ImportError: cannot import name update_contenttypes"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

Traceback:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "my_script.py", line 16, in <module>
        django.setup()
      File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 112, in create
        mod = import_module(mod_path)
      File "c:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\apps.py", line 7, in
    <module>
        from .management import update_contenttypes
    ImportError: cannot import name update_contenttypes
```

The script used to run fine until I attempted to update django-allauth (which updated a ton of other packages: pytz, requests, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, and Django (though I Ctrl-C'd when it started wanting to update Django. I am using Django 1.8.5)

Comment: Are you using virtualenv or python3 venv? If not you should start using it, define the exact versions of your packages with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and put those into your version system. That way you can recreate your installation any time even if an update should break it like you described. You can always roll back to the versions you specified in requirements.txt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name update\_all\_contenttypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550102/importerror-cannot-import-name-update-all-contenttypes)