# imoprt error when I gave source toaster start in morty

Tags: django, yocto

I got below error when i run poky/build$ `source toaster start`.

```
The system will start.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siva/yocto/Morty/poky/bitbake/bin/../lib/toaster/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
......   
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed



 File "/home/siva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/apps.py", line 7, in <module>
 from .management import update_contenttypes  
    ImportError: cannot import name 'update_contenttypes'
```

I have seen the below link but I believe That is diiferent than this.

[importerror: cannot import name update _all_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550102/importerror-cannot-import-name-update-all-contenttypes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using two yocto sources like krogoth and morty.

`krogoth` depends on python2 and pip
`morty` depends on python3 and pip3
It might have confused things. So please use below command:

```
 rm -rf /home/siva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django
```

Comment: Thanks@Vadalasetti sivanageswararao. your saying correct . and its working for me after deleting the dir(django).

Answer (score 0):

You can import like that,

```
from YourPackageName.management import update_contenttypes
```

Comment: I have written like this still same error
 "  from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes ""